# Posting to Twitter with PHP timing out

Tags: php, twitter

I've tried a dozen libraries and everything I can think of but I just can't get the tweet to appear on Twitter. The code is getting hung up on something.

Here's the current library I'm using http://pastebin.com/7Y6wirpD

Here's the code being used. Keys have been removed.

```
require_once 'php/twitteroauth.php';

define("CONSUMER_KEY", "***");
define("CONSUMER_SECRET", "***");
define("OAUTH_TOKEN", "***");
define("OAUTH_SECRET", "***");
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET);
$content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
$connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => 'Test Tweet!'));
```

Any ideas?

Comment: checked if your server/firewall allow outbound connections from the webserver process? don't blame the library - there's many places where things could be going wrong, and the library's just one of them.

Comment: Tried several libraries. They all seem to end up hanging so I'm pretty sure it's not the library or I'd at least have had a different error. It's hosted on 000webhost while being developed and I've checked that all connections are working. Also checked cUrl is enabled.

Comment: then bypass the libraries entirely and try doing a post from other code directly, e.g. a quick dirty `post -> google.com` or something. see if ANYTHING is reachable.

Comment: Thanks for your time Mark. The last library I used was logging in to Twitter successfully. It only hangs when I get to send.